# ATI Driver for HP Pavilion dv2 notebook?

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, amd-radeon

I'm looking for a Windows XP Professional (32-bit) ATI video driver for an HP Pavilion dv2 (model 1118nr).

I've downloaded and run several drivers packages, but none have worked so far. The notebook has a sticker on it that reads, "ATI Radeon Premium Graphics 3000 Series"

The notebook has an AMD Athlon Neo 64 CPU and it came with Vista 64, but I have a requirement to run 32-bit Windows XP.

Does such a driver exist, and if so, where is it?

I've tried the [AMD ATI graphics drivers portal](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx), but the "Mobility Radeon" section does not list the 3000 series. The "Radeon" section does list the 3000 series, but the package I downloaded and installed from there was not helpful.

I also selected "All Graphics - Notebook" on the ["Search Drivers and Downloads" page](http://support.amd.com/us/Pages/drivers.aspx), then selected "Windows XP Professional/Home" on the OS drop down, pressed "Submit", and downloaded and installed the only choice (this single choice is listed twice), but again, it didn't seem to help.

Answer (score 1):

Your laptop has a ATi Mobility Radeon Premium Graphics 3410, but as you mentioned its not available on their page directly. There is a workaround, have a look at [this thread](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/psg/board/message?board.id=OS&message.id=12152&query.id=111870#M12152).

> First You must install .Net Framework
> [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=0856EACB-4362-4B0D-8EDD-AAB15C5E04F5&displaylang=en)
>
> ATi HD 3410 Graphics driver [here](http://game.amd.com/us-en/drivers_catalyst.aspx?p=xp/radeonx-xp)
>
> If it does not get installed then use
> method below.
>
> For this card, ATI does NOT release
> Windows XP drivers.
>
> However, you may utilize Mobility
> Modder by driverheaven.net.
>
> Download the following files
>
> 1. Download MSXML 6.0 from Microsoft, [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=D21C292C-368B-4CE1-9DAB-3E9827B70604&displaylang=en)
> 2. Download Mobility Modder, [here](http://www.driverheaven.net/frontpage/modtool/MMDotNETSetup1200.zip)
>
> Follow these steps:
>
> 1. Install .Net Framework,
> 2. Download newest desktop drivers, (You've already downloaded it - refer
>    top)
> 3. Run Catalyst Software Suite but cancel the installation once the
>    driver is extracted.
> 4. Run Mobility Modder, browse to the driver in C:ATI/SUPPORT/xxxxx/ --> hit
>    modify. Wait until driver is modified.
> 5. Wait until Install is finished and reboot.

Comment: Thanks for the links, but none of these suggestions worked for me.